GNOME terminal "use colors from system theme" not working
I am having trouble with making the GNOME terminal's color scheme follow the general GNOME color scheme with the "use colors from system theme" checked.

I get a dark-themed terminal.

The general theme being light.

Is this the expected behavior, or am I missing something?

I have this problem as well.

I have the same issue, so I opened an issue for us at GNOME Terminal's issue tracker. A maintainer responded right away, that the version I'm using (GNOME Terminal 3.44.0 for GNOME 42 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) is too old, and that the bug in this version therefore won't be fixed. Assuming that you are using the same or a similar version, we are SOL.
However, I have just found a workaround which I am happy with, which is to replace gnome-terminal with wezterm. An example configuration for switching light/dark themes based on the system theme is provided here, that worked for me right away, and there are many pretty color schemes available by default, so you can choose ones you like for your light & dark themes. I chose 'One Light (Gogh)' and 'Jellybeans' respectively for mine.

Thank you very much for your answer! It seems that updating the gnome-terminal doesn't fix the problem, I added that to the issue you created on the gnome gitlab.
